# check if twitter is connected for iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

How can I check that I can make a TWRequest on Twitter for iOS5 since I don't have an access token in place? With the regular twitter REST API using frameworks such as MGTwitterEngine we can do a check for the access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need it. In iOS5 you just need to put the username and pwd in iOS settings. You just need to use the `TWTweetComposeViewController` and manage its callback block (`completitionHandler`) correctly. In the block you receive statuses about the operation.

```
TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult Possible values for the result parameter of the completionHandler property.

enum TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult {
    TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled,
    TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone };
 typedef enum TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult;
```

If need to know if you can send tweet just use the class method `+ (BOOL)canSendTweet` of the class `TWTweetComposeViewController` .
If you need more control you can use the `TWRequest` instead of the `TWTweetComposeViewController`. 
Check here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html

Comment: I am talking about doing TWRequest, not TWTweetComposer

Comment: Try to create the TWRequest using the account verify credential parameter https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api? <br>GET account/verify_credentials  Returns an HTTP 200 OK response code and a representation of the requesting user if authentication was successful; returns a 401 status code and an error message if not. Use this method to test if supplied user credentials are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:)

```
-(IBAction)updateTwitter:(id)sender {

    [tweetTextField resignFirstResponder];

    if(![_engine isAuthorized]){ 
        UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];
        if (controller) {
            [self presentModalViewController:controller  animated:YES];
        }
    }else
    {
        [_engine sendUpdate:tweetTextField.text];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is using MGTwitterEngine, I am talking about the built in iOS 5 Twitter